# azure runbook enable guest level diagnostics

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-runbook

I am working on a PowerShell runbook to look at all vms in the azure subscription, find out if guest level monitoring is not enabled and enable it

Following is the command I am using to enable the diags.

```
Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName xxxxxx -VMName xxxxxx -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $diagnosticsconfig_path -StorageAccountName xxxxxx
```

I am thinking of storing the diag xml file in a storage blog, how do I point to it with $diagnosticsconfig_path ?

If I use

```
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -blob "xxx.json" -Container xxx -Context $storageAccount.Context 

or

Get-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName 'xxx' -Context $storageAccount.Context -path xxx.json
```

The runbook can download the file but how do I refer to this file as the diagpath in Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the command below, you are no need to download the file, we can point the path directly to the blob url.

```
$SAResourceGroupName="<Storage Account ResourceGroupName>"
$StorageAccountName="<StorageAccountName>"

$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
$Context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$tmpStart = Get-Date
$tmpEnd = $tmpStart.AddHours(2.0)
$SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob "diagnostics_publicconfig.xml" -Container "111" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $tmpStart -ExpiryTime $tmpEnd -FullURI

Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -VMName joyVM -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "$SASToken" -StorageAccountName joystoragev2
```

[image]

In the runbook:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy for the response, 

Following is what I am getting when I try the script
Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension : Illegal characters in path. 

I tried something similar before by manually created the SAS and fed it to variable $diagnosticsconfig_path and it gave me same error.

Comment: @Deb I test it in the runbook, it also works, see my update, could you provide your specific command? especially the `-DiagnosticsConfigurationPath` you used.

Comment: $SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob "GLD.json" -Container "scripts" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $tmpStart -ExpiryTime $tmpEnd -FullURI


Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName deb_nonprod -VMName AZINF3001 -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $SASToken -StorageAccountName nonproddiag980

Comment: I tried in Azure runbook too and it gave me same error. Does it matter if the storage blob has more than 1 file in it?

Comment: Tried creating a fresh storage account created blob and placed file there, still didnt work.

Comment: `$SASToken = https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/GLD.json?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=xxxxXXXX01010101xxxx1M%3D&st=2018-11-22T11%3A39%3A34Z&se=2018-11-22T13%3A39%3A34Z&sp=r`

Comment: I tried modifying the link by adding `&amp;` in place of `&` now its throwing a different error `Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

Comment: @Deb Your token looks fine, but my file is a `.xml` file, you could have a try.

Comment: yes that worked, wonder y it didn't work as .json.
However what I did for the xml is copied the sample xml from `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-windows` changed the resource id and storageaccount and applied it.
Applied fine, but now when I try to change the settings in the portal (eg. Sample rate of processor time) it says `Update failed` .
Also in this case for every VM I will need a separate xml, thats gona be a pain.

Comment: @Deb If it works, please mark my reply as answer, there is an option to mark on the left of my reply, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for great script . Let me define the entire process in steps:

1. Go to [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-windows#sample-diagnostics-configuration), copy the XML sample file, paste in powershell and save as XML.
2. Select one storage account, select a container and upload the XML file.
3. Now use this script to enable or change the exiting storage account.

```
    $VMRGName = (Get-AzureRmResource -Name $VMName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" ).ResourceGroupName
    $StorageAccountName= "storageaccount01"
    $SAResourceGroupName= (Get-AzureRmResource -Name $diagstoragename -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts').ResourceGroupName
    $storagecontainer = "test"
    $StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
    $Context= New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
    $tmpStart = Get-Date
    $tmpEnd = $tmpStart.AddHours(2.0)
    $SASToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Blob "DiagnosticsPubConfig.xml" -Container $storagecontainer -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $tmpStart -ExpiryTime $tmpEnd -FullURI
    #to SET
    Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName $VMRGName -VMName $VMName  -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "$SASToken" -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName 
    #to GET
    $publicsettings = (Get-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension  -ResourceGroupName $VMRGName -VMName $VMName).PublicSettings
    $encodedconfig = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $publicsettings).StorageAccount
```

Comment: " paste in powershell and save as XML" how does powershell save a file?

Comment: save as - XML .

Comment: today I have created a better script . entire thing is automated .